# Angular 2 updating @ViewChildren when updating *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I add a new widget and changed its name, but inside @ViewChildren ngWidgets the name isn't changed.  How can this change be reflected inside the view children.

```
@Component({
selector:'grid',
template :<widget *ngFor="let widget of widgets" ></widget>
});
export class grid{

@ViewChildren(NgWidget) ngWidgets : QueryList<NgWidget>;
public widgets:Array<NgWidget>=[];

ngAfterViewInit(){
var newWidget = new NgWidget();
newWidget.name = 'lun';
this.widgets.push(newWidget);
}
}

@Component({
selector:'widget',
template:'div [innerHTML]="name"></div>
})
export class ngWidget{
public name='';
}
```

The widget inside ngWidgets doesn't have the name therefore its not displayed inside my widget template.

Comment: Can you post the component with the selector `widget`?

Comment: Hi, I posted the component.  The name isn't shown.  What I noticed was that the widget in ngWidgets doesn't have the name.

Comment: You have to pass `name` as `@Input` property. This `var newWidget = new NgWidget();` doesn't create angular component

Comment: You should also not new up an `ngWidget` component, that isn't doing what you think. You'll want to iterate over a list of something that then generates the `widgets` via the `*ngFor`

Comment: Ok.  Thanks, Yeah I'll not new the ngWidget component.